# Python Splinter geckodriver PATH OSX

Tags: python, selenium, geckodriver, splinter, path-variables

After reading numerous answers on StackOverflow, I found that in order to get Splinter to work, I needed to add the geckodriver executable to my PATH variable.

Here's what I did:

In terminal:

```
echo 'export PATH=$PATH: /Applications/anaconda/pkgs/geckodriver
```

I then confirmed it was in there via:

```
echo $PATH
```

...which shows:

```
/Applications/anaconda/pkgs/geckodriver:...
```

Then I tried this (after restarting my Spyder IDE):

```
from splinter import Browser
browser = Browser('firefox')
```

...and STILL go this error:

```
WebDriverException: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH.
```

Comment: The path separator on OSX is `:`, you have an extra space before `/Applications/` which is probably what's causing the issue

Comment: I just tried with echo 'export PATH=$PATH:/Applications/anaconda/pkgs/geckodriver (no extra space) but no dice. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

move your `geckodriver` binary to /usr/bin/

Answer (score 1):

From [linfo.org](http://www.linfo.org/path_env_var.html) (emphasis my own):

> PATH is an environmental variable in Linux and other Unix-like
>   operating systems that tells the shell **which directories to search for**
>   executable files

In other words, the problem (besides the extra space in your path) was that you added the path to the binary file itself to your search path instead of the *directory* which contained that binary.  If you tried again with `export PATH=$PATH:/Applications/anaconda/pkgs` and confirmed that the `geckodriver` binary is executable and lives directly inside the `/Applications/anaconda/pkgs` directory (or any other directory in the path) things should work as expected.

Alternately, you can of course place your binary in one of the directories already in your search path by default on OSX, such as `/usr/local/bin`, `/bin` or as @Rubi Jihantoro suggests, `/usr/bin`

In order to find out if the shell can find your binary, you can always run `which` on that binary and it'll print out where the binary was found, if anywhere, e.g.

```
> which geckodriver
/Applications/anaconda/pkgs/geckodriver
```